How to animate Text widget based on TextField's controller value?
I have a TextField with its controller and a Text widget, I want to listen to the changes in the TextEditingController and animate the value inside the Text widget.
I want 2 distinguishable animations, one when adding a character and the other when removing a character from the TextField.
This is the desired result
I have tried to iterate over each character in the TextEditingController inside a Row widget then render a Text widget containing that value wrapped with a TweenAnimationBuilder and a unique key, the result is working when adding a character only.

one question, does it have constraints? like you only going to add numbers at the end and remove from the end, you can't remove or insert numbers in the middle of the existing string, is that correct?

it's a TextField, so users can enter values at any index, but even if they added or removed a number from the middle or the beginning, I want to animate only the last item in the TextEditingController, something like this : https://i.sstatic.net/743I9.gif

It's a bit tricky, I prepared a widget for you.
When adding new numbers

When deleting numbers

Code:
class NumberAnimationSample extends StatefulWidget {
  const NumberAnimationSample({super.key});

  @override
  State<NumberAnimationSample> createState() => _NumberAnimationSampleState();
}

class _NumberAnimationSampleState extends State<NumberAnimationSample> {
  String? digits;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      body: Center(
        child: SizedBox(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.5,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.blue[800],
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                    children: [
                      const Text(
                        'Number',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontSize: 20,
                        ),
                      ),
                      AnimatedDigitsWidget(
                        digits: digits,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                  child: TextField(
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(label: Text('Number')),
                    style: const TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 25,
                    ),
                    onChanged: (value) {
                      setState(
                        () {
                          digits = value;
                        },
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class AnimatedDigitsWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const AnimatedDigitsWidget({this.digits, super.key});

  final String? digits;

  @override
  State<AnimatedDigitsWidget> createState() => _AnimatedDigitsWidgetState();
}

class _AnimatedDigitsWidgetState extends State<AnimatedDigitsWidget> {
  String currentWidgets = '';
  final _animatedDigits = <_MyCustomAnimatedDigit>[];
  final _animationControllers = <AnimationController>[];

  @override
  void didUpdateWidget(covariant AnimatedDigitsWidget oldWidget) {
    if (oldWidget.digits != widget.digits) {
      currentWidgets = widget.digits ?? '';
      if ((oldWidget.digits?.length ?? 0) < currentWidgets.length) {
        _animatedDigits.clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < currentWidgets.length; i++) {
          _animatedDigits.add(
            _MyCustomAnimatedDigit(
              digit: currentWidgets[i],
              onControllerCreated: (controller) {
                _animationControllers.add(controller);
                if (i == currentWidgets.length - 1) {
                  controller.forward();
                }
              },
            ),
          );
        }
      } else {
        var removedDigitsLength =
            (oldWidget.digits?.length ?? 0) - currentWidgets.length;
        AnimationController? controller;
        for (int i = 0; i < removedDigitsLength; i++) {
          if (i == 0) {
            controller = _animationControllers.removeLast();
          } else {
            _animationControllers.removeLast();
          }
        }
        controller?.reverse().whenComplete(
          () {
            setState(
              () {
                _animatedDigits.clear();
                for (int i = 0; i < currentWidgets.length; i++) {
                  _animatedDigits.add(
                    _MyCustomAnimatedDigit(
                      digit: currentWidgets[i],
                      onControllerCreated: (controller) {},
                    ),
                  );
                }
              },
            );
          },
        );
      }
    }
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: [
        for (final digit in _animatedDigits) digit,
      ],
    );
  }
}

class _MyCustomAnimatedDigit extends StatefulWidget {
  const _MyCustomAnimatedDigit({
    required this.digit,
    required this.onControllerCreated,
  });
  final String digit;
  final ValueChanged<AnimationController> onControllerCreated;

  @override
  State<_MyCustomAnimatedDigit> createState() => __MyCustomAnimatedDigitState();
}

class __MyCustomAnimatedDigitState extends State<_MyCustomAnimatedDigit>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late AnimationController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 250),
    );
    widget.onControllerCreated(_controller);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnimatedBuilder(
      animation: _controller,
      builder: (context, child) {
        return Opacity(
          opacity: Curves.easeOut.transform(_controller.value),
          child: Transform.rotate(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            angle: lerpDouble(
                -pi / 4, 0, Curves.easeOut.transform(_controller.value))!,
            child: child,
          ),
        );
      },
      child: Text(
        widget.digit,
        style: const TextStyle(
          fontSize: 25,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


I've submitting an edit with a little bit of change in the code to get the animation that I want. Also, there was a bug when trying to access a disposed animation controller, I didn't know you can have such control with the didUpdateWidget lifecycle, thanks a lot.
